# Arc-Consistency (AC3) and one Challenges?

Tags: constraints, artificial-intelligence, backtracking, sat, constraint-satisfaction

In Applying Arc-Consistency (AC3) algorithms on one Constraint Satisfaction Problem, if domain of one variable be empty, what is the next step?

```
1) halt.

2) do backtrack.

3) start from another initial state.

4) it depends on that we are in which step.
```

Solution (4). I think (1) is true because it mean we cannot find any consistent assignment and halt. anyone can describe why (4) is true?

Answer (score 2):

With the [particular algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC-3_algorithm) you're using, if the domain of a variable shrinks until it is empty, then it means that the constraint problem has no solutions.  Therefore the algorithm should halt in the failure state.

Comment: but solution says (4) !!

Comment: your solution is exactly wrong.  Since we only remove values from domains when they can never be part of a solution, an empty domain means no solution possible at all ----> so  back out of that branch... no halt start from other branches...

Comment: maybe stop , maybe backtrack or maybe start from another branch, please see page 221 from this books: https://books.google.com/books?id=ms7BbRjEwo8C&pg=PA221&lpg=PA221&dq=arc-consistency+domain+empty+backtrack+and&source=bl&ots=68AG9qCjoo&sig=tnxE-wIW76druM3T5sOSWUtv-M8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4hfqbtcTNAhWBFiwKHb_QAbc4ChDoAQhGMAc#v=onepage&q=arc-consistency%20domain%20empty%20backtrack%20and&f=false